# Check for setMapType availability

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mapkit, ios9

With iOS 9 new map types have been added related to flyovers.  I would like to make sure the user is on iOS 9 before offering that map type.

Currently in Xcode 7 the highest foundation number they have is: `NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_8_3` Of course that doesn't work as 8.4 was the last 8.x release.  They do not offer either 8.4 or 9.0.

I also cannot use something like respondsToSelector as `setMapType` is valid in all versions and the value isn't checked as part of this method.

I saw some posts about checking for the existence of the constant, which in this case would be `MKMapTypeHybridFlyover` but that isn't working either.

What is best to use here to see that the user has access to this map type?

Update: I look at the value of `MKMapTypeHybridFlyover` both under iOS 8.4 and iOS 9 and in both cases it shows 4 (at least on the sim).  So I cannot use the value or lack thereof to determine whether it is supported.  This brings me back to checking the iOS version but as mentioned above the floor offered is 8.3 which means it won't work for 8.4 which probably everyone that is still on 8.x is running....

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used to solve the issue in terms of checking the OS version:

```
 NSOperatingSystemVersion version = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo]operatingSystemVersion];  

    if (version.majorVersion > 8)  
       ....  
    else  
        ....
```